# Scipy rotation result is different from np.matmul

Tags: scipy, transform

On this [webpage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.apply.html#scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.apply), it gave an example of how to use scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.apply. The example is as follows.

```
vector = np.array([1, 0, 0])
r = R.from_rotvec([0, 0, np.pi/2])
r.as_matrix()
>> array([[ 2.22044605e-16, -1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 1.00000000e+00,  2.22044605e-16,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00]])
r.apply(vector)
>> array([2.22044605e-16, 1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00])
```

I am confused by the result. Shouldn't the final results be [0, -1, 0] because of the following code

```
rotation_matrix = np.array([[ 2.22044605e-16, -1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
 [ 1.00000000e+00,  2.22044605e-16,  0.00000000e+00],
 [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00]])
vector = np.array([1, 0, 0])
np.matmul(vector, rotation_matrix)
>> array([2.22044605e-16, -1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00])
```

Comment: what does `rotation_matrix @ vector` produce?  That's the order in `self.as_matrix().dot(vectors)`